# Locally works, fails on server : Google calendar API

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

In an existing Java based spring boot application, I have integrated Google calendar API. In my local, it works. On dev server, I see that the URL to open in browser is :

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events
```

where the redirect uri is http://localhost:8080/Callback instead of https://dev.myserver.in/Callback which results in invalid request

even if I correct the URI manually and past in the browser, it says 404.

I have created the service account and provided redirect uris for localhost and my dev server, and I am using the same as credential.json file in my code.

Following are code snippets

```
private Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = GoogleCalendarServiceImpl.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);

        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }

        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
                clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(tokensDirectoryPath)))
                        .setAccessType("offline")
                        .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build(); //.Builder().setPort(localServerReceiverPort).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }
```

and here it is used:

```
public void createEvent(CreateEventRequest request) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

    Event event = createEvent(request);
    String calendarId = "primary";
    Event createdEvent = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();

    log.info("Event successfully created! : {} ", createdEvent.getHtmlLink());

}
```

Here are the configs :

```
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Calendar";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credential.json";
    
    @Value("${google.calendar.tokens.directory.path}")
    private String tokensDirectoryPath
    
    
    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart. If modifying these
     * scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_EVENTS);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using

```
new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
```

This is for use with installed applications. Installed applications use localhost as the redirect uri.

For web server aplcistons you should be using [GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/f4068b68a5db46086fd1db60f6dce91e0dc263c7/docs/oauth-2.0.md#web-server-applications)

```
public class CalendarServletSample extends AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException {
    // do stuff
  }

  @Override
  protected String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
    GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(req.getRequestURL().toString());
    url.setRawPath("/oauth2callback");
    return url.build();
  }

  @Override
  protected AuthorizationCodeFlow initializeFlow() throws IOException {
    return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        new NetHttpTransport(), GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
        "[[ENTER YOUR CLIENT ID]]", "[[ENTER YOUR CLIENT SECRET]]",
        Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)).setDataStoreFactory(
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY).setAccessType("offline").build();
  }

  @Override
  protected String getUserId(HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // return user ID
  }
}

public class CalendarServletCallbackSample extends AbstractAuthorizationCodeCallbackServlet {

  @Override
  protected void onSuccess(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, Credential credential)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.sendRedirect("/");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onError(
      HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, AuthorizationCodeResponseUrl errorResponse)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    // handle error
  }

  @Override
  protected String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
    GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(req.getRequestURL().toString());
    url.setRawPath("/oauth2callback");
    return url.build();
  }

  @Override
  protected AuthorizationCodeFlow initializeFlow() throws IOException {
    return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        new NetHttpTransport(), GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
        "[[ENTER YOUR CLIENT ID]]", "[[ENTER YOUR CLIENT SECRET]]",
        Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)).setDataStoreFactory(
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY).setAccessType("offline").build();
  }

  @Override
  protected String getUserId(HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // return user ID
  }
}
```

Also ensure that you created Web application credentials On google cloud console and not installed application credentials.

- [How to create Google Oauth2 web application credentials in 2021.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBVAyU4pZOU)